# Certificates in rubyonrails and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I was following Railscast tutorial on how to implement Paypal to your application.

In this tutorial he store certificates created by `OpenSSL` locally in the applications folder called `Certs`.

He then calls those certs with these commands:

```
PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert.pem")
APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_cert.pem")
APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_key.pem")
```

But I'm guessing this is not the safest or correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options:

**Config variables**

```
heroku config:add APP_KEY_PEM="...your certificate..."
```

This is probably the easiest way to have some information stored 'locally' on your app servers.

**Mix of repositories**

Have separate repository for your application with sensitive data. When you update your main application, pull it from that repository, and then push to heroku. If you are the only person who has access to the repository anyway, and you are sure that no one *will ever* have access to it (otherwise you'll need to clean up history as well as working tree files), then there is no problem in the first place.